# Finding $\mathbb{P}(N=k)$ where $N$ is the minimum of some integers

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$.
Once $U$ is known, we have additional r.v.s $X_1,\ldots$ also from the Uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.
Let $N$ be the number such that $N$ is the smallest $n$ for $X_n \geq U$.
Find $\mathbb{P}(N=k)$.

This is what I tried:
$$N = \min\{n:X_n \geq U\}.
$$
So
$$\mathbb{P}(N=k) = \mathbb{P}(X_k \geq U) \\ = 1- \mathbb{P}(X_k < U) \\ = 1 - \int_{\text{all} \ x_k} I(0<x_k<1)\ dx_k \\ = 1 - \int_0^u 1 \ d x_k \\ = 1-u 
$$
however this seems to be in terms of $u$ and not even $k$....

Comment: Conditioned on $U = u$, we can call $X_N$ the first "success", with each trial being Bernoulli with success change of $p = 1-u$. That is, $N$ has conditionally a Geometric distribution. You thus integrate for this Geo which parameter is uniform.

Comment: The mistake in your own derivation is that you completely forgot about the behavior of $X_i$ for $i < k$ when you set $N = k$.

Comment: Cool! Thank you -- what if the Question changed and $U$ was in $[2,3]$ for example instead (and also $X_k$ was in $Unif(2,3)$)?  
What would the parameter be? (since $1-u$ wouldn't be in $[0,1]$)

Comment: It's exactly the same, Make a change of variable $U_s = U - 2$, then $U_s$ has a standard uniform. We will have $p = 1-u_s$ which is $3-u$.

Comment: $$\mathbb{P}(N=k) = \mathbb{P}(\{X_k \geq U\} \cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{n}\{X_k < U\})$$ How to proceed? Are the $X_k$'s independent? So many random variables. So much conditioning.

Answer (score 1):

One can certainly condition on $U=u$ and then integrate over $u$, but here is an approach without integration:

$P(N=k) = P(X_k \ge U > X_i \ \ \forall i \in \{1, 2, ..., k-1\}) = \frac{1}{k+1} \frac{1}{k}$, because this is simply the probably that out of $k+1$ independent and identically distributed (iid) r.v.s, a specific r.v. ($X_k$) comes first and another specific r.v. ($U$) comes second.  It doesnt even matter that each of them is uniform.  (All we need is to have zero probability of any two r.v.s being exactly equal.)

If you really want integration, let $F(x) = P(X\le x)$ be the CDF, and to avoid exact equality among r.v.s, assume $F$ is differentiable and the PDF is $f(x) = F'(x)$.  Then we have $P(N=k | U=u) = F(u)^{k-1} (1-F(u))$.  Then integrate over $u$:

$$P(N=k) = \int_{range\ of\ u} F(u)^{k-1} (1 - F(u)) f(u) du \\ = \int^1_0 F(u)^{k-1} (1 - F(u)) dF(u) \\ = \int^1_0 y^{k-1} (1-y) dy = \bigg[\frac{y^k}{k} - \frac{y^{k+1}}{k+1} \bigg]^1_0 = \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$

and it is clear that the exact distribution doesn't matter as long as it is differentiable / has zero probability of two r.v.s with exactly equal values.